# Match everything between TWO separator charcters

Tags: regex

I want to match everything between seperators that constist of two characters left and right. E.g. `<<Hello>>` where `<<` and `>>` are the seperators. That works with regex `\<\<([^\>]+)\>\>`.

But it need to be possible to have the single separator characters `<` and `>` in the *matched* string, like `<<\<Hello\>>>` where `\<Hello\>` should match.

This does not work.

I tried a negative lookahead: `\<\<((?!\>)[^\>]+)\>\>` with no success.

I need to be able to escape the separator characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `<<([^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*)>>`, see https://regex101.com/r/0CiEbi/1

Comment: Thank you!! That's it ... almost... When I try it on `<<Hello\>\>>>` it matches `<<Hello\>\\` (with a backslash at the end but not the following `>`)

Comment: Could you please add some valid/invalid strings? BTW, with the above ``<<Hello\>\>>>`` string, the captured value is ``Hello\>\>``, see https://regex101.com/r/0CiEbi/2

Comment: This `<<Hello\>\>>> <<Test>>` should give two matches: `Hello\>\>` and `Test`

Comment: I tested it with PowerShell (.NET):

`$r = [regex]"<<([^>]*(?:>(?!>)[^>]*)*)>>"; $r.Matches("<<Hello\>\>>> <<Test>>").groups`

That results in:

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 12
Value    : <<Hallo\>\>>

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 2
Length   : 8
Value    : Hallo\>\

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 14
Length   : 8
Value    : <<Test>>

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 16
Length   : 4
Value    : Test

Comment: They do, see https://regex101.com/r/0CiEbi/3 Just get the captured values in Group 1

Comment: looks great in regex101! It's a PowerShell/.net problem.

Comment: I tried it in http://regexstorm.net/tester with pattern `\<\<([^\>]*(?:\>(?!\>)[^>]*)*)\>\>` and in input `<<Hello\>>>`. there it matches `<<Hello\>\`

Comment: I tested it: `"<<Hello\>\>>> <<Test>>" | Select-String -Pattern '<<([^>]*(?:>(?!>)[^>]*)*)>>' -AllMatches | % {$_.matches.groups[1].value}` Same result : `<<Hello\>\\`

Comment: Yes. The group value is important. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Your second expression does also not add the last second escaped `>` to the group and returns also `Hello\>\\`

Comment: You are using my older suggestion in these comments and I was pasting it instead of the latest one, please remove them all - see my top comment, use `'<<([^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*)>>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$r = [regex]'(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)<<([^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*)>>'
$res = $r.Matches('<<Hello\>\>>> <<Test>>') | % {$_.Groups[1].value}
```

Or

```
$res = $s | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)<<([^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*)>>' -AllMatches | % {$_.matches.groups[1].value}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%7b2%7d%29*%29%3c%3c%28%5b%5e%5c%5c%3e%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%5c%5c%3e%5d*%29*%29%3e%3e&i=e+%3c%3c%5c%3cHello%5c%3e%3e%3e+%0d%0a%3c%3cHello%5c%3e%5c%3e%3e%3e%0d%0a%3c%3cHello%5c%3e%5c%3e%3e%3e+%3c%3cTest%3e%3e).

If you wish to get the matches without accessing Group 1 put `<<` and `>>` into `(?<=<<)` lookbehind / `(?=>>)` lookahead:

```
$r = [regex]'(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*<<)[^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*(?=>>)'
$res = $r.Matches("<<Hello\>\>>> <<Test>>") | % {$_.value}
```

Or

```
 $res = $s | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*<<)[^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*(?=>>)' -AllMatches | % {$_.matches.value}
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%7b2%7d%29*%3c%3c%29%5b%5e%5c%5c%3e%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%5c%5c%3e%5d*%29*%28%3f%3d%3e%3e%29&i=e+%3c%3c%5c%3cHello%5c%3e%3e%3e+%0d%0a%3c%3cHello%5c%3e%5c%3e%3e%3e%0d%0a%3c%3cHello%5c%3e%5c%3e%3e%3e+%3c%3cTest%3e%3e).

Output:

```
Hello\>\>
Test
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)` - the first `<` in the initial `<<` cannot itself be escaped, else, it is not a valid match
- `<<` - a `<<` substring
- `([^\\>]*(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^\\>]*` - 0 or more chars other than `\` and `>`
  - `(?:\\.[^\\>]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of any escaped char but newline and then 0 or more chars other than `\` and `>`
- `>>` - a `>>` substring.

Comment: That looks great! Thank you, Wiktor!!

Comment: @IngoKarstein Actually, there must be `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)` at the start of the pattern. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this pattern `(?<=<<).+?(?=>>)`

Explanation:

`(?<=<<)` - positive lookbehind, assures that what's before is `<<`

`.+?` - match one or more of any characters, non-greedy

`(?=>>)` - positive lookahead, assures that what follows is `>>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVFCcT/2)

Comment: This is not working in every case: When I test `<<Hello>><<Test>>` I get the group `Hello>><<Test`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this:

```
\<{2}(.*?)\>{2}(?!\>)
```

You get your desired output in group 1.

Explanation:

1. `\<{2}` start with 2 <<
2. `(.*?)\>{2}` match everything unless it reaches two consecutive >>
3. `(?!\>)` after step 2 is true it must make sure that the next character is     not  > ( negative lookahead)

[Regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/e5gNok/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern: `<<(.*?[^\\]?)(?=>>)>>`

It works for the following cases:

```
<<\<Hello\>>>
<<Hello>><<Test>>
<<>>
```

[See explanation...](https://regex101.com/r/L7ZGJU/1)